# DI EF Core, console app error Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

In program.cs i have created a  configure services method

```
 private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory()
            .AddSerilog());
        serviceCollection.AddLogging();
        serviceCollection.AddDbContext<Spiderdb>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=SpiderDB1;Integrated Security=True"));



        // Initialize serilog logger
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .WriteTo.File("app.log")
             .MinimumLevel.Debug()
             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
             .CreateLogger();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<App>();
    }
```

This is how i'm using/ injecting

```
class App
{

        private readonly ILogger<App> _logger;
        private readonly Spiderdb _spiderDb;


        public App(ILogger<App> logger, Spiderdb context)
        {
          _logger = logger;
          _spiderDb = context;
        }

        public async void RunAsync()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting App");

            using (_spiderDb)
            {
                var x = await _spiderDb.ProxyServersProviders.ToListAsync();
            }
        }

}
```

same connection string works fine if I don't inject and I use SQLServer instead of SQLlite, but not with DI. the classes for the models & context are built using EF power tools, but that's likely a red herring, is the connection string is not correct for SQL lite or have I not injected/registered correctly ?

Curiously the log mentions  An 'IServiceProvider' was created for 
internal use by Entity Framework. which I'm sure I've seen somewhere & is to do with DI ?

```
2018-07-21 06:42:39.004 +01:00 [DBG] An 'IServiceProvider' was created for 
internal use by Entity Framework.
2018-07-21 06:42:39.101 +01:00 [INF] Starting App
2018-07-21 06:42:40.160 +01:00 [INF] Entity Framework Core 2.1.1-rtm-30846 
initialized 'Spiderdb' using provider 
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
2018-07-21 06:42:40.356 +01:00 [DBG] Compiling query model: 
'from ProxyServersProvider <generated>_0 in DbSet<ProxyServersProvider>
select [<generated>_0]'
2018-07-21 06:42:40.413 +01:00 [DBG] Optimized query model: 
'from ProxyServersProvider <generated>_0 in DbSet<ProxyServersProvider>
select [<generated>_0]'
2018-07-21 06:42:40.691 +01:00 [DBG] (QueryContext queryContext) => 
IAsyncEnumerable<ProxyServersProvider> _InterceptExceptions(
source: IAsyncEnumerable<ProxyServersProvider> _TrackEntities(
    results: IAsyncEnumerable<ProxyServersProvider> _ShapedQuery(
        queryContext: queryContext, 
        shaperCommandContext: SelectExpression: 
            SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[DailyReqCount], [p].[DailyReqLimit], [p]. 
[FailedCount], [p].[FirstReqToday], [p].[IsRestAPI], [p].[LastReq], [p].[URL]
            FROM [ProxyServersProviders] AS [p], 
        shaper: UnbufferedEntityShaper<ProxyServersProvider>), 
    queryContext: queryContext, 
    entityTrackingInfos: { itemType: ProxyServersProvider }, 
    entityAccessors: List<Func<ProxyServersProvider, object>> 
    { 
        Func<ProxyServersProvider, ProxyServersProvider>, 
    }
), 
contextType: Spider.EF.Spiderdb, 
logger: DiagnosticsLogger<Query>, 
queryContext: queryContext)
2018-07-21 06:42:40.814 +01:00 [DBG] Opening connection to database 
'SpiderDB1' on server '(localdb)\ProjectsV13'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this format.

```
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<Spiderdb>(options => options.UseSqlite("Server=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13;Database=SpiderDB1;Trusted_Connection=True"));
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings